# Question on weak star convergence in subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be some normed linear space and let $X^\ast$ denote its dual space endowed with the weak star topology. Let $U^\ast$ be some subspace of $X^\ast$.

If I want to show that $\varphi_n$ converges in $U^\ast$ (and therefore in $X$?) is it enough to show $\varphi_n(u)\to \varphi(u)$ for all $u \in U$ or do I have to show it for all $x \in X$?

Comment: What is $U$?  You defined $U^*$ as a subspace of $X^*$, but this does **not** mean that $U^*$ is a dual space.

Comment: Do you think that it will be easy to find $U$ (whatever it is)?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Could you show me an example of $X^\ast$ and $U^\ast$ where I cannot determine $U$ from $U^\ast$?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Could you show me an example of $X^\ast$ and $U^\ast$ where I cannot determine $U$ from $U^\ast$? Also, what is a good book to study these things from? I know it's functional analysis but which part of functinal analysis is this?

Comment: You didn't say what $U$ is supposed to be.  Before trying to determine it, you need to say what it is supposed to be.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I want $U$ to be the subspace of $X$ such that the dual of $U$ equals $U^\ast$. And given some subspace $U^\ast$ of $X^\ast$ I want to be able to determine $U$.

Comment: The dual of a subspace $U$ of $X$ is **not** a subspace of $X^*$.  Instead, every member of $X^*$ determines a bounded linear functional on $U$, its restriction to $U$.  The restriction map is not one-to-one.  The dual of $U$ can be identified as the quotient  $X^*/U^\perp$ where $U^\perp$ is the subspace of $X^*$ consisting of functionals that are $0$ on $U$.